# if statement for changing serial output breaks the integer used for rest of code

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to get back in to coding so i am re-teaching myself some basics before i tackle a bigger project.
This fault is confusing the *.* out of me.

I have modified the fading LED code from the beginner pages to now include a dual colour led and now serial and lcd screen output of the current state of the led.
(My project will include all of these hence the combo).

All was well with the fading led.
It starts off,  fades up in green, when at max brightness, turns off green, switches to red then fades down.
Switches back to green and repeats.

Then i added serial and LCD output and now, the led colour part of the code breaks when ever i try and reference the currently active led pin to write that colour (As a string) to serial.

My code is below.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h> ///LCD library

int ledr = 6;         // the PWM pin the red LED is attached to
int ledg = 5;         // the PWM pin the green LED is attached to
int led;              // the active LED pin
int brightness = 0;   // how bright the LED is
int fadeAmount = 10;  // how many points to fade the LED by
//char colour;           // to use for displaying led colour as string in serial and lcd
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 20, 4); //I2C LCD display address 0x27 with 20 cells x 4 rows display

void setup() {
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);                                   // setup pin for led
  Serial.begin(9600);                                     // start serial  
  analogWrite(13, 0);                                     // turn off led 13
//  Serial.println("Green fade up - Red fade down");       // write this to serial
//  delay(1000);                                           // wait 1 sec to see it in serial
  led = ledg;                                             // set led active pin to ledg

  }

void loop() {
  if (brightness <= 0) {                // if brightness <= 0,
  led = ledg;                           // set active led to ledg (green)
//  colour = 'Green';
 };

  if (brightness >= 255) {              // if brightness >=255, turn off last led (ledg, green), acivate ledr (red) with one cycle crossover.
  led = ledr ;                          // set active led to ledr (red)
  analogWrite(led, 255);                // set active led (ledr, red) to 100%
  led = ledg;                           // set active led to ledg (green)
 analogWrite(led, 0);                   // set active led ledg (green) to off
 led = ledr;
// colour = 'Red';                            // set led to ledr (red)

 };
  
  analogWrite(led, brightness);         // set active led to current brightness

  
  brightness = brightness + fadeAmount; // change the brightness for next time through the loop:

  
  if (brightness <= 0 || brightness >= 255) {   // reverse the direction of the fading at the ends of the fade:
    fadeAmount = -fadeAmount;
  };


                                   // below is outout to serial
  Serial.print(led);               // print the current active led pin and brightness to serial in the format (pin" - "brightness")
  Serial.print("  -  ");           // print " - "
//  Serial.print(colour);            // print the current colour of the led

// if (led = 5); {
//  Serial.print("Green");
//   };
  
//if (led = 6); {
// Serial.print("Red");
//  };
  
  Serial.print("  -  ");          // print " - "
  Serial.println(brightness);     // print the brightnesss of the led

                                  // below is outout to LCD  
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);            // move cursor the first row
  lcd.print("LED Pin + Colour");  // print message on the first row
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);            // move cursor to the second row
  lcd.print(led);                 // print active led pin on the second row then
  lcd.print(" : ");               // print "+" then
//  led.print(colour);              // print the colour of the currently active led
  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);            // move cursor to the third row
  lcd.print("LED PWM (0-255)");   // print message on the third row
  lcd.setCursor(0, 3);            // move cursor to the fourth row

  if (brightness <= 99) {         // if to check for <100 brightness value and clear 3rd cell if true.
    lcd.setCursor(2, 3)  ;        // move cursor to line 4, cell 3
    lcd.print(" ");               // clear cell
    };                            // end if

  lcd.setCursor(0,3);             //move cursor back to start of row 4
  lcd.print(brightness);          // print message the fourth row
  delay(50);                      // wait for (x) milliseconds to slow the dimming effect
}
```

Please ignore the references to **char colour**. thats a different issue i'm having :(

When i un-comment either or both of the if statements below ** Serial.print(colour); ** it breaks. the led still fades in and out but the colour change stops working and it will only fade using the colour of the if statement i'm using.

Below is a good led switch without either if statements active
Led 6 (red) fades out and led 5 (green) fades up

```
6  -    -  40
6  -    -  30
6  -    -  20
6  -    -  10
6  -    -  0
5  -    -  10
5  -    -  20
5  -    -  30
5  -    -  40
```

Below is with the first if active active

```
5  -  Green  -  40
5  -  Green  -  30
5  -  Green  -  20
5  -  Green  -  10
5  -  Green  -  0
5  -  Green  -  10
5  -  Green  -  20
5  -  Green  -  30
5  -  Green  -  40
```

(green (string) is now shown as the if is active).
Green (5) was on when it should have been red.
Same thing with only the other if active but it would have been Red.

with both active,

```
6  -  GreenRed  -  40
6  -  GreenRed  -  30
6  -  GreenRed  -  20
6  -  GreenRed  -  10
6  -  GreenRed  -  0
5  -  GreenRed  -  10
6  -  GreenRed  -  20
6  -  GreenRed  -  30
6  -  GreenRed  -  40
```

Now, both colours are displayed despite the if statements and apart from the brief switch from 6 to 5 and back to 6 (It is supposed to, see code), the led is stuck on pin 6 (red)

I have tried if/else and two if statements and it has no effect.
from what i can tell, it is just the reference to (led = 5) or (led = 6) that causes the issue.

please help. I've spent 2 days trying to work it out and i am not very very confused.

Thanks.

Comment: The thing you've asked about (now answered) the commented out code `colour = 'Green';` (not a string) are both things you should get warnings for if you increase the warning level in the IDE. May have saved you the two days.

Comment: `i am not very very confused` ... isn't  that a good thing?

Comment: your code is very messy... it is not not indented correctly ... please format your code sobthat each block is clearly delimited

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with = vs. ==.  One equal sign for assignment, two for comparison.  You also shouldn't have a semicolon on an if statement.  That semicolon acts as the only thing controlled by the if.  It translates to "if this then do nothing".  You want the stuff in brackets to be controlled by the if statement.  So no semicolon.

```
 if (led == 5) {
  Serial.print("Green");
 }
```

Comment: Awesome. thank you. I did not know the difference between = and ==.
I did know about the semicolon. I missed that one. Much appreciated.